# Convert TTreeview selection to Object list - Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

Using a TreeView to display all tables in a database I need to convert the table elements (name, fields, etc.) selected into a TObjectList for later use.

Is there a way to convert the TTreeView to a TObjectList?

Comment: Just do it the other way around. Fill the list, fill the tree from the list.

Comment: @user3207517:  You have the TTreeView and TObjectList the wrong way around in "Is there a way ..." question, but even then the question seems misconceived.  At most, all you need to load into the TTreeView is a string representing the name of the individual metadataitems (Table/Dataset names, FieldNames, etc) and the objects they are obtained from.  The later depends on the type of Database/Dataset objects you are using.  Try putting together some code that retrieves the metadata and populates the TTreeView and post your code if you get stuck.